# MongoDb connection with Node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to setup Mongo DB with my nodejs application . I created an account in mongoDb Atlas and I am trying to connect my app with the below URL with my username and password . Unfortunately I am getting authentication Fail error .

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;


const CONNECTION_URL = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@renj0-2herp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true";
const DATABASE_NAME = "example";

var app = Express();

app.use(BodyParser.json());
app.use(BodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

var database, collection;

app.post("/person", (request, response) => {
    collection.insert(request.body, (error, result) => {
        if(error) {
            return response.status(500).send(error);
        }
        response.send(result.result);
    });
});

app.get("/people", (request, response) => {
    collection.find({}).toArray((error, result) => {
        if(error) {
            return response.status(500).send(error);
        }
        response.send(result);
    });
});

app.listen(3001, () => {
    MongoClient.connect(CONNECTION_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (error, client) => {
        if(error) {
            throw error;
        }
        database = client.db(DATABASE_NAME);
        collection = database.collection("people");
        console.log("Connected to `" + DATABASE_NAME + "`!");
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you putting your username and password inside <> this angle bracket?

Comment: no .. without those

Comment: Ok, then please recheck your credentials

Comment: I have rechecked it many times .. IS it anything to do with ATLAS ?

Comment: Can you please show me the error?

Comment: ` throw err;
      ^

MongoError: authentication fail
    at /home/ranjit/AuthDemo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/replset.js:1458:15
    at /home/ranjit/AuthDemo/node_modules/mongodb
`

Comment: `mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0-1q7ty.mongodb.net/test` This is a sampte connection string.
Your connection string should have the cluster. Please recheck it from mongodb atlas

Answer (score 2):

```
const CONNECTION_URL = 'mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/example'
```

Your connection url is wrong so i suggest you try this format or try below also

```
const CONNECTION_URL = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/example'
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to whitelist your IP adders with MongoDb Atlas. To do so, open cmd/terminal and run command "ipconfig" and search for "IPv4 Address" and copy the IP address.
Now, open your Atlas cluster, goto security, and there you will find the option IP whitelist, click ADD IP ADDRESS and add you IP.

Comment: I chose connect any in the IP whitelist option so that any IP can connect

Comment: check you connection string (do not add "<" and ">" in user name and password). To find the connection string go to the Cluster Overview click Connect, select 2nd option connect to your application, Select Driver as NodeJS (By default) select Version, and below you will find connection string copy paste that and change user name and password. 
(do not add "<" and ">" in user name and password)

Comment: Ya I know that . I have entered just the username and password without < and >